# Insert element at nth position in Array with numpy.insert

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, insert

I try to insert np.nan values into an array at the nth position. Desired output:

> array(['1', 'nan', 'nan', '2', test', '3'])

I tried with this code:

```
position = [1,2]
array= np.array([1,2,'test', 3])
array= np.insert(array, position, np.nan)
```

But it is inserting the values at index 1 and 3:

> array(['1', 'nan', '2', 'nan', 'test', '3'])

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you really starting with a numpy array?  Note that while your `array` definition has a mix of numbers and str, the result is string dtype.  And the `np.nan` is inserted as a string.  In a comment you talk about replacing 'string types' with `nan` in a `dataset`.  That sounds more like a `pandas` operation.  Remember `np.nan` is a `float`.  Do you want to mix integers, floats, and strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting would take place altogether for both `np.nan`. So, if you use `[1,2]` then index 1 would be between `1` and `2`, and index 2 would be between `2` and `'test'`.
The position needs to be `[1,1]` if you want to insert continuous values.

```
import numpy as np

position = [1,1]
array = np.array([1,2,'test', 3])
array = np.insert(array, position, np.nan)
print(array)
```

Output:

```
['1' 'nan' 'nan' '2' 'test' '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

The position should be [1, 1]. Position 2 is between 2 and 'test' and 1 is between 1 and 2. The index where you insert them is where the index is located in the initial array, not where they will end up.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy.insert() function **inserts values *before the given indices.***

*i.e.*
for the given array :

```
[1, 2,'test',3]
 0  1   2    3   -> index
```

Inserting at position=[1,2] will insert values before index 1 (value =2) and before index 2(value ='test') in the original array i.e.

```
[1, ___, 2, ___, 'test',3]
```

In order to get both nan inserted before index 1, write as

```
import numpy as np
position = [1,1]
array= np.array([1,2,'test', 3])
array= np.insert(array, position, np.nan)
print(array)
```

You will get the desired result:

```
['1' 'nan' 'nan' '2' 'test' '3']
```

> *Note: This position array is not the index of the new values you want to insert, it is the index before which you want to insert the new values*